# How to get list that is the distinct select of other lists (LINQ)?

Tags: linq

Sorry about the question, I couldn't build the sentence. Here is what I have,

```
class Brand{
    int ModelId;
    string name;
}

class Gallery{

    IList<Brand> brands;
    ...
    public BrandList{
        get{ return brands; }
    }
}
```

I have a list of Gallery. Like this,

```
IList<Gallery> galleries;
```

and each Gallery in galleries have many Brands in it. For example, galleries have 6 Gallery object in it. And each gallery has Brands in it. Like this,

```
Gallery1.Brandlist => Audi, Ford 
Gallery2.BrandList => Mercedes,Volvo 
Gallery3.BrandList => Subaru 
Gallery4.BrandList => Renault 
Gallery5.BrandList => Subaru 
Gallery6.BrandList =>
```

What I am trying to get with LINQ is a list of Brands that are distinct of all above's first brand only(so I won't take Ford and Volvo even they are in the list). A gallery doesn't have to have a Brand in their list. So it might be empty as Gallery6. The Output should be,

```
{Audi, Mercedes, Subaru, Renault}
```

I don't know how I can do this with LINQ. I tried `SelectMany` but all I can do with LINQ is simple `(p=>p.Something = (int) something).ToList()`. I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: What means: _"distinct of all above's first brand only"_?

Comment: each Gallery's BrandList's first Brand

Comment: Now i get it, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: Why there is no Ford and Volvo in your expected result?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Because he only wants a distinct list of all the **first** brands in the galleries(Ford and Volvo are second brands in these galleries), i also haven't understood that point until now.

Comment: Extremely strange requirement, but +1 for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) and [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx):</strike>

```
IEnumerable<string> allUniqueBrands = allGalleries
    .SelectMany(g => g.BrandList.Select(b => b.Name)).Distinct();
```

In query syntax:

```
IEnumerable<string> allBrands = from gallery in allGalleries
                                from brand in gallery.BrandList
                                select brand.Name;
IEnumerable<string> allUniqueBrands = allBrands.Distinct();
```

**Edit**: Now i got it, you need only the first brands of each BrandList.

If you want to select the `Brand` you have to provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<Brand>` which you can use in `Distinct`. If you neeed a `List<Brand>`, just call `ToList()` at the end.

Here's an `IEqualityComparer<Brand>` for `Distinct` (or Union,Intesect,Except etc):

```
public class BrandComparer : IEqualityComparer<Brand>
{
    public bool Equals(Brand x, Brand y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.Name.Equals(y.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Brand obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return int.MinValue;
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and here's the distinct list of all (first) brands:

```
List<Brand> uniqueFirstBrands = allGalleries
    .Where(g => g.BrandList != null && g.BrandList.Any())
    .Select(g => g.BrandList.First())
    .Distinct(new BrandComparer())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I won't have Ford and Volvo. Can I change the IEnumerable to IList and <string> to <Brand>?

Comment: If you want to select the `Brand` you have to provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<Brand>` which you can use in `Distinct`. If you neeed a `List<Brand>` call `ToList()` last. @RaphaëlAlthaus: I must admit that i'm not sure what you mean after i read the question again. But maybe i've misunderstood the requirement.

Comment: @Ada: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I already have GetHashCode in all of my objects. I wrote the question as Brand and Gallery but now since I go deep in the objects, I figured out they are 4 list depth. I will modify yours, I think I understood it. Thank you very much

Comment: Also, you used g in the second and third row. Do they have to be both g? I need to divide it into parts(because I will also check the type). I will write as list=  allGalleries.Where(g=>g.BrandList..).ToList();  otherlist = list.Select(p=>p....)

Comment: @Ada: `g` is just the variable name of the projected gallery instance. You can name it whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting confused when there are more than 1 selects in a row :)

Comment: SubstanceList = SubstanceList.OfType<Drug>().ToList();
            IList<TestResult> TestResults = SubstanceList.SelectMany(g => g. TestResultList).ToList();
            TestResults = TestResults.Where(p => p.TestType == (int)TestEnum.TestType.DrugTest).ToList();
            IList<Relation> Relations = TestResults.Where(p => p.SubstanceAmount.Any()).Select(p => p. SubstanceAmount.FirstOrDefault()).Where(p => p.NameId > 0).Distinct().ToList();
            IList<Int32> NameIdList = Relations.Select(p => p.nameId).ToList();
This is what I changed it into.

Comment: The names are silly,I had to translate them to English. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
var brands = galleries.Where(x => x.BrandList.Any())
                      .Select(x => x.BrandList.First().Name)
                      .Distinct();
```

If you want the result being a collection of Brand objects instead of strings, you could do this:

```
var brands = galleries.Where(x => x.BrandList.Any())
                      .GroupBy(x => x.BrandList.First().Name)
                      .Select(g => g.First().BrandList.First());
```

Comment: @Ada: sorry, I forgot to pick the name property. Check my edit ;)

Comment: Now I figured out there is no ModelId in my Brand object. The ModelId's are also a list in brand :( Guess I need to add another select now?

Comment: @Ada: I modified my answer just 1 min ago. Try it, maybe now it fits more your needs ?